# Javafx 8 Scrollpane content headers not position correctly

Tags: javafx-8, scrollpane

The objective is to display a table like content, but in this case with 2 sets of labels, the normal vertical labels and horizontal labels, the two must be able to scroll and keep the labels visible at all times.

I thought i had it figure out, it works in the beginning but the more you scroll the more the banner gets out of position, it seems to be accumulating some error in positioning a long the way..don't know here, or if i'm doing something wrong..

Runing javafx 8.25 on Win7

My code:

```
package com.hdk.tests;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class TestScrollPaneBanners extends Application {

boolean photoYInited = false;
boolean photoHInited = false;

ImageView photoY ;
ImageView photoX;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setPrefSize(400, 400);
    scrollPane.setMaxSize(400, 400);

    BorderPane panel = new BorderPane();
    panel.setPrefSize(600, 600);
    HBox horizontalStripp= new HBox();
     horizontalStripp.setPrefHeight(35);
     horizontalStripp.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    horizontalStripp.getChildren().add(new Label("Vertical"));
    HBox header = new HBox();
    HBox.setHgrow(header, Priority.ALWAYS);
     header.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    header.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red;");
    Label tl = new Label("This is the top label.....");
    tl.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    header.getChildren().add(tl);
    horizontalStripp.getChildren().add(header);


    panel.setTop(horizontalStripp);
    scrollPane.setContent(panel);
    VBox verticalStripp = new VBox();
    verticalStripp.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue;");
    verticalStripp.getChildren().add(new Label("Vertical"));
    verticalStripp.getChildren().add(new Label("Vertical"));
    verticalStripp.getChildren().add(new Label("Vertical"));
    verticalStripp.getChildren().add(new Label("Vertical"));
    verticalStripp.getChildren().add(new Label("Vertical"));
    verticalStripp.getChildren().add(new Label("Vertical"));
    panel.setLeft(verticalStripp);



    Label infoX = new Label();
    Label infoY = new Label();
    scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener( new InvalidationListener(){

        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {

            double visibleHeight = panel.getHeight()-scrollPane.getPrefHeight();             
            double posX = visibleHeight*scrollPane.getVvalue();
            boolean visible = posX<header.getHeight();
              String tx ="VisibleY ="+ visible+ " V ="+scrollPane.getVvalue() ;               
            if(!visible){
                //take photo
                if(!photoYInited){
                    //init image
                      WritableImage sns = header.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
                        photoY = new ImageView(sns);
                        photoYInited = true;
                        panel.getChildren().add(photoY);
                }
               //position image in borderpane               
                   photoY.setLayoutY(posX);              
                   photoY.setLayoutX(header.getLayoutX());
                   tx+=" Cx "+header.getLayoutX()+" Cy "+posX;
            }else{
                //its visible
                //remove photo if present
                if(photoYInited){
                    panel.getChildren().remove(photoY);
                    photoYInited = false;
                }
            }
             infoY.setText(tx);

        }

    });
    scrollPane.hvalueProperty().addListener( new InvalidationListener(){

        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {      

            double visibleWidth = panel.getWidth()-scrollPane.getWidth();

            double posX = visibleWidth*scrollPane.getHvalue();
            boolean visible = posX < verticalStripp.getWidth();
              String tx ="VisibleX ="+ visible+ " H ="+scrollPane.getHvalue() ;

            if(!visible){
                //take photo
                if(!photoHInited){
                    //init image
                      WritableImage sns = verticalStripp.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
                        photoX = new ImageView(sns);
                        photoHInited = true;
                        panel.getChildren().add(photoX);
                }               
                   photoX.setLayoutX(posX);
                   photoX.setLayoutY(verticalStripp.getLayoutY());                    
                   tx+=" Cx "+posX+" Cy "+verticalStripp.getLayoutY();
            }else{
                //its visible
                //remove photo if present
                if(photoHInited){
                    panel.getChildren().remove(photoX);
                    photoHInited = false;
                }
            }
             infoX.setText(tx);

        }

    });       
    VBox all = new VBox();
    all.getChildren().add(scrollPane);
    all.getChildren().add(infoX);
    all.getChildren().add(infoY);     

    Scene scene = new Scene(all, 400, 500);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello Banner!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're putting a BorderPane inside a ScrollPane. I'm guessing this combination may not work as expected. Note that ScrollPane is a Control and not a Pane like BorderPane is. Why it doesn't work is probably in the technical details of how these classes handle their resizing, etc, and you might have a really hard time figuring it out. I would suggest trying some other approach, it's not really clear from your description what you'd like to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!I thought about that but didn't seem logic, but programing isn't always logic..Will try it out with another pane maybe that's the problem..

Answer (score 0):

why not consider open source project? like [fxcontrols](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/)
[image]
the screen shot above is spreadsheet view, is that what you want?

Comment: No quite, my needs were more like the scrollpane in swing, with columns and row headers..I made a solution in javafx but forgot to post it here, there is no javafx equivalent of that function at the time i'm writing.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** For some wired reason StackExchange coudn't show my whole code. Anyway, **visit here to see the full code**: http://pastebin.com/87rsNyAA

Add a BorderPane. On the center of BorderPane, add ScrollPane. At top and left of the BorderPane, add two Pane for Horizontal and Vertical rule. Now from the ScrollPane's HValue and VValue property, get those HValue and VValue and change the Horizontal/Vertical Pane's location at the Top or Left accordingly.

[Application Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFxJg.png)

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.Insets;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
    import javafx.scene.effect.DropShadow;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.stage.Screen;
    import javafx.scene.text.Text;
    import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
    import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
    import javafx.scene.shape.Line;

    /**
     *
     * @author Zunayed Hassan
     */
    public class ScrollPaneWithRuler extends Application {

        final static double DPI = Screen.getPrimary().getDpi();
        final static double THICKNESS_OF_RULER = DPI * 0.5;
        final static int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1024;
        final static int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 768;
        final static int CONTENT_WIDTH = 2500;
        final static int CONTENT_HEIGHT = 2500;

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {        
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

            // Inside of the scroll pane
            ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
            scrollPane.setStyle("-fx-background: gray;");
            scrollPane.setPrefViewportWidth(800);
            scrollPane.setPrefViewportHeight(600);
            root.setCenter(scrollPane);

            Pane artBoard = new Pane();
            artBoard.setPrefSize(CONTENT_WIDTH, CONTENT_HEIGHT);
            scrollPane.setContent(artBoard);

            Pane canvas = new Pane();
            canvas.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.WHITE, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            canvas.setPrefSize(600, 500);
            canvas.setEffect(new DropShadow(5, 1, 1, Color.BLACK));
            canvas.setTranslateX(50);
            canvas.setTranslateY(50);
            artBoard.getChildren().add(canvas);

            // ----------------------------------------------------------------


            // Row Header
            Pane verticalRulePane = new Pane();
            verticalRulePane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.web("#F4F4F4"), CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
            root.setLeft(verticalRulePane);

            Pane vRule = new Pane();
            vRule.setPrefWidth(THICKNESS_OF_RULER);
            verticalRulePane.getChildren().add(vRule);

            for (int i = 0; i  changeListenerForHorizontalScroll = new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                    hRule.setTranslateX(-((CONTENT_WIDTH - WINDOW_WIDTH) * scrollPane.getHvalue()));
                }
            };

            scrollPane.hvalueProperty().addListener(changeListenerForHorizontalScroll);

            ChangeListener changeListenerForVerticalScroll = new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                    vRule.setTranslateY(-((CONTENT_HEIGHT - WINDOW_HEIGHT) * scrollPane.getVvalue()));
                }
            };

            scrollPane.vvalueProperty().addListener(changeListenerForVerticalScroll);

            // ----------------------------------------------------------------

            Scene scene = new Scene(root, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

            primaryStage.setTitle("ScrollPane with Ruler");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }

    }
```